# Invoking a no-argument Action from an event that takes arguments

Tags: c#, delegates, closures

I'm trying to write a convenience method, intended to help bind a generic delegate to a class event.

The key part of this, is the event on the class takes 1 or more arguments (eg object, and various params), and I want the wrapped action to take 0 arguments.

A quick example of this would be:

```
public class Test
{
    //Other class.  <int,bool> is just an example, it could be anything
    public event Action<int, bool> MyEvent;

    //Helper
    public void AddAction(Action a, object cls, string eventName)
    {
        var evt = cls.GetType().GetEvent(eventName);

        //Need some code in here to wrap the action
        evt.AddEventHandler(cls, a);
    }
}
```

Obviously the above code will probably throw an exception when we try to run it.

Edit: I should elaborate.  I know I can just do `(a,b) => a()`, but in this case, I don't know the event's type ahead of time.

What I'd like is to be able to generate a new delegate, that takes in `int`, `bool` and then invokes the action internally.

I've tried writing a DynamicMethod/ILGenerator, without much luck, so I'm looking for input and suggestions for how to do this.  As far as I know, IL Generation is the only way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you make a simple edit on this line `var event = cls.GetType().GetEvent(eventName);`because event is a keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent many many hours to figure this out, and ended up circling back to Linq Expressions.

The main problem with DynamicMethod, which it took me a while to realize, is that it doesn't have scope.  When it's built, it can be thought of as a static set of instructions, and thus, it doesn't know what 'this' is (unless you pass it as an argument).

What I ended up doing is compiling an expression with the expected arguments, and calling into the expected method on the delegate.

Here's some example code:

```
public static class AnonymousAction
{
    public static Delegate WrapDelegate(Action action, Type targetType)
    {
        var invoke = targetType.GetMethod ("Invoke");
        if (invoke == null)
            throw new ArgumentException ("ofType must be delegate");

        var parameters = invoke.GetParameters ();
        var expressionParams = new ParameterExpression[parameters.Length];
        for (int i=0; i<parameters.Length; ++i)
        {
            expressionParams [i] = Expression.Parameter (parameters [i].ParameterType);
        }

        var call = Expression.Call (
            Expression.Constant(action),
            typeof(Action).GetMethod ("Invoke")
            );

        return Expression.Lambda (targetType, call, expressionParams).Compile ();
    }
}

public class MyReceiver
{
    public event Action<MyReceiver, int> OnAction;

    public void Do()
    {
        OnAction (this, 22);
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public void Run()
    {
        Action onAction = () => {
            Console.WriteLine ("Did something");
        };

        var receiver = new MyReceiver ();
        var evt = receiver.GetType ().GetEvent ("OnAction");
        evt.AddEventHandler (receiver, AnonymousAction.WrapDelegate (onAction, evt.EventHandlerType));

        receiver.Do ();
    }
}
static void Main()
{
    var t = new Test ();
    t.Run ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to rename your `var event`line of code: it will not compile because event is a key word used as you did up and not in an expression. You said "**What I'd like is to be able to generate a new delegate, that takes in int, bool and then invokes the action internally**"

Here is how I would do it using anonymous delegates. I am editing my previous post to correct a mistake.

Assuming that your MyEvent will be hooked up with some Event handling code somewhere like:

```
 public void HookUpTheEventWithTheHandler()
    {
        MyEvent += MyEventHandler;

    }

    public void MyEventHandler(int x, bool condition)
    {
        // Do some processing here....
    }
```

I assume therefore that It won't be null next:

My AddAction method could look like:

```
    public void AddAction(Action<int,bool> a, object cls, string eventName)
    {
        var eventVar = cls.GetType().GetEvent(eventName);
          a += delegate(int x, bool condition)
        {
            MyEvent(x, condition);
        };

          eventVar.AddEventHandler(cls, a);

    }
```

Now if you don't know the types ahead of time then you probably need to use generecity.

Here is how I would do it

```
public class Test<I, B> {
    ....
     public event Action<I, B> MyEvent2;

      public void AddAction2(Action<I, B> a, object cls, string eventName)
      {
          var eventVar = cls.GetType().GetEvent(eventName);
          a += delegate(I x, B condition)
          {
              MyEvent2(x, condition);
          };

          eventVar.AddEventHandler(cls, a);

      }
```

Comment: Thanks. Here's the thing, though. I don't *know* the arguments are `int,bool`.  I'm using that as an example for this case, they could be anything.  I'll edit my question to demonstrate this.

Comment: Your parameters can be anything as long as you tell the compiler that you are using generic types. I have edited my contrib to illustrate this

Comment: I don't even know the count of the parameters, just the Type of it via GetEvent.